# How to solve error: 'Missing arguments for parameters 'data', 'detailedData' in call'

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to make a detailed view of a contact from a contacts list. This is the WIP of that view. I am getting the error;

> Missing arguments for parameters 'data', 'detailedData' in call

on the line with `ContactDetail()` in the `ContactDetail_Previews` struct.

I think I understand that this is because something is missing from the variables data and detailedData, but my confusion comes from how I use similar code for the actual list view of all the contacts, with no such error. I have pasted the code for the whole list view below the code for the detailed view.

Any help would be appreciated!

Contact Detail Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContactDetail: View {
    var data: Response_Detailed.Contact_Detailed
    @ObservedObject var detailedData: getData_Detailed

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(data.first_name + " " + data.last_name)
            Text(data.phone_number)
            Text(data.birthday)
            Text(data.address)
            Text(data.updated_date)
            Text(data.create_date)
                .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    self.detailedData.updateDetailed_Data()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class getData_Detailed: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data = [Response_Detailed.Contact_Detailed]()
    @Published var id = 1
    
    init() {
        updateDetailed_Data()
    }
    
    func updateDetailed_Data() {
        let url = "DATABASE_LINK\(id)"
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, _, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response_Detailed.self, from: data!)
                let oldData = self.data
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.data = oldData + json.data
                    
                    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
                    let data = try! encoder.encode(json)
                                            
                    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContactDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContactDetail()
    }
}

struct Response_Detailed: Codable {
    struct Contact_Detailed: Codable, Identifiable {
        public let id: Int
        public let first_name: String
        public let last_name: String
        public let birthday: String
        public let phone_number: String
        public let create_date: String
        public let updated_date: String
        public let address: String
    }
    public let data: [Contact_Detailed]
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
    }
}
```

Contacts List View Code: (Note the same error comes up on the line with `NavigationLink`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                ContactsList()
                    .navigationBarTitle("Contacts")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 20.0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContactsList: View {
    @ObservedObject var listData = getData()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<listData.data.count, id: \.self) {i in
            NavigationLink(destination: ContactDetail()) {

                if i == self.listData.data.count - 1 {
                    cellView(data: self.listData.data[i], isLast: true, listData: self.listData)
                }
                else {
                    cellView(data: self.listData.data[i], isLast: false, listData: self.listData)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct cellView: View {
    var data: Response.Contact
    var isLast: Bool
    @ObservedObject var listData: getData
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
            if self.isLast {
                Text(data.first_name + " " + data.last_name)
                    .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .padding(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/[.leading, .bottom, .trailing], 5.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .onAppear {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                            self.listData.updateData()
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                Text(data.first_name + " " + data.last_name)
                    .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .padding(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/[.leading, .bottom, .trailing], 5.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 10)
    }
}

class getData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data = [Response.Contact]()
    @Published var limit = 15
    @Published var skip = 0
    
    init() {
        updateData()
    }
    
    func updateData() {
        let url = "DATABASE_LINK?skip=\(skip)&limit=\(limit)"
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, _, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!)
                let oldData = self.data
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.data = oldData + json.data
                    self.limit += 15
                    self.skip += 15
                    
                    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
                    let data = try! encoder.encode(json)
                                            
                    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Response: Codable {
    struct Contact: Codable, Identifiable {
        public let id: Int
        public let first_name: String
        public let last_name: String
        public let updated_date: String
    }
    struct Pagination_Data: Codable {
        public let skip: Int
        public let limit: Int
        public let total: Int
    }
    public let data: [Contact]
    public let pagination: Pagination_Data
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
        case pagination = "pagination"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ContactsList` is giving the only variable an initial value.

```
@ObservedObject var listData = getData()
```

Not IAW Apple documentation but the `= getData()` is the initial value

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

BTW you should change it to

```
@StateObject var listData = getData()
```

Your `ContactDetail` `View` has two variables without an initial value

```
struct ContactDetail: View {
    var data: Response_Detailed.Contact_Detailed
    @ObservedObject var detailedData: getData_Detailed
```

No `=` sign so a `struct` creates an `init` that looks like this

```
init(data: Response_Detailed.Contact_Detailed, detailedData: getData_Detailed)
```

So in your Preview you need to provide the initial values

```
ContactDetail(data: /.../, detailedData: /.../)
```

The `/.../` symbolizes where you will provide sample data

Comment: I see what's happening here, I just need to provide some initial values or use =. May I ask how exactly do I provide the initial values, and what do I provide in there. Just a  bit of clarification on that would be helpful. Also, why exactly does this issue not come up for `data` variable in ContactsList, but does for the ContactDetail?

Comment: It happens because the variables in the detailed view don’t have initial values. The first part of my answer details why. I can’t give you initial values for your previews because you have not provided enough information to give you that. This is why I left it blank. What code do you have that generates test data? You likely don’t want to do API calls during previews because the calls will happen every time you make a minor change.